# Strange CSS behavior with box and multi-column list

Tags: html, css, list

I'd like a three-column list inside a grey box:

```
<div style="width:500px;font-size:21px;background:#f5f5f5;margin:0 0 40px 100px;padding:1px;border:3px solid black;">
  <div style="text-align:center;margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;"><strong>Table of Contents</strong></div>
  <ul style="float:left;width:33%;list-style-type:none;">
   <li>Book 1.</li>
   <li>Part 1.</li>
   <li><a href="#S1">Section 1.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#S2">Section 2.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#S3">Section 3.</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul style="float:left;width:33%;list-style-type:none;">
   <li>Book 2.</li>
   <li>Part 1.</li>
   <li><a href="#S4">Section 1.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#S5">Section 2.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#S6">Section 3.</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul style="float:left;width:33%;list-style-type:none;">
   <li>Book 3.</li>
   <li>Part 1.</li>
   <li><a href="#S7">Section 1.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#S8">Section 2.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#S9">Section 3.</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But the results are not pretty: http://jsfiddle.net/gq2gh/

Can anyone explain what's going on, and/or fix it? Thanks.

Comment: There aren't three columns (only two and then a third stuck at the bottom), and they aren't inside the grey box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `width:33%`. The 33% are relative to your `<body>` tag, which makes the columns too wide. Specify an absolute width in `px`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves one problem. But how do I get the columns inside the grey box?

Comment: Even simpler: use `overflow: auto`. See a working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/gq2gh/2/)

Comment: @chopper Unfortunately, the columns aren't centered, and when I enter the correct value of 166px (500/3), the original problem returns: http://jsfiddle.net/gq2gh/4/

Comment: That's because `ul` had a padding of `40px` specified. If you override and set it to `0px`, it works. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/gq2gh/5/). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @chopper Good eye on the padding, but the columns are still very badly off-center. And if I increase the 166 to bring the middle column to the center, it only reintroduces the original problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gq2gh/6/

Comment: Well that's because your text in your columns is left-aligned. Have you tried `text-align:center`? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/gq2gh/7/)

Comment: @chopper That centers the text within the columns, as well as the columns themselves.

Comment: It does. I'm not quite sure what you are looking for. By assigning a `width` of `166px` you are effectively 'centering' the middle column. But the text within the column is left-aligned, which is why it _looks_ off-center.

Comment: You also could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/gq2gh/8/), where you use irregular column positioning, but it really depends on what exactly you want and on how your content looks.

Comment: @chopper I ended up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/gq2gh/9/. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if you let me be sincere, why don't you use a `<table>` if your intention is to create a **table**? Why work with CSS if what you want may be achieved with a simple tag?

I know the use of `<table>` has been kind of "demonized" because of past designs, but in your case, using it is not only simpler but more correct, as you would be using a tag which was **created** for your problem.

Here is the code of a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2gh/12/) demonstrating what I'm talking about.

```
<div class="outer_box">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Table of Contents</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                    <li>Book 1.</li>
                    <li>Part 1.</li>
                    <li><a href="#S1">Section 1.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#S2">Section 2.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#S3">Section 3.</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                    <li>Book 2.</li>
                    <li>Part 1.</li>
                    <li><a href="#S4">Section 1.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#S5">Section 2.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#S6">Section 3.</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                    <li>Book 3.</li>
                    <li>Part 1.</li>
                    <li><a href="#S7">Section 1.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#S8">Section 2.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#S9">Section 3.</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```